# groovy: iterate functions over loops

Tags: groovy

Consider two collections:

```
collect1 = ['file.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']
collect2 = ['/tmp/','/home/', '/dev/']
```

with:

```
def collection = new File("/path/to/file.txt").readLines()
def collection2 = { new  File("/tmp/").listFiles }
```

How to iterate functions like `def collection` and `def collection2` through those values from collect1 and collect2

Desired result:

```
def collection = new File("file.txt").readLines()
def collection2 = { new  File("/tmp/").listFiles }
def collection = new File("file2.txt").readLines()
def collection2 = { new  File("/home/").listFiles }
def collection = new File("file3.txt").readLines()
def collection2 = { new  File("/dev/").listFiles }
```

Comment: Please add the programming language tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `collect` over the collection, which is a "map" (often called
that in other programming languages).  It transforms each item of the
collection and "collects" the results eagerly for you.

```
def collect2 = ['/tmp/','/home/', '/dev/']

def files = collect2.collect{ (it as File).listFiles().toList() }

println files*.take(2)
// → [[/tmp/.X11-unix, /tmp/.ICE-unix], [/home/user], [/dev/cpu, /dev/vcsa63]]
```

If you want to join the results, there is also `collectMany`, which will
give you a single collection with all the results concatted.

```
def collect2 = ['/tmp/','/home/', '/dev/']

def files = collect2.collectMany{ (it as File).listFiles().toList() }

println files.take(5)
// → [/tmp/.X11-unix, /tmp/.ICE-unix, /tmp/.XIM-unix, /tmp/.font-unix, /tmp/.Test-unix]
```